# How to upload a file to AnonFiles service using pure Java?

Tags: java, file, http, upload

I have found many api's for anon files, but they all use different libs
I need to upload a file to anonfiles by using pure java and get it's download link

What to do next?

`File file = ....; HttpURLConnection httpcon = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL("https://api.anonfiles.com/upload").openConnection()); httpcon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");`

Comment: Apparently, you can’t anymore: https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/file-sharing-site-anonfiles-shuts-down-due-to-overwhelming-abuse/